# Erro ao escolher o tema para formulario

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou fazendo um formulário e ao escolher o tema Dialog ele informa que:
Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?
conforme vocês podem ver abaixo. Se é que não possa realmente utilizar este tema, tem outra maneira de deixar o formulário com aparência mais amigável?

[image: erro]

Aqui esta meu styles
[image: eero3]

e aqui é como esta meu formulario atualmente:

[image: erros]

Comment: basta fazer o que ele tá pedindo, ou seja, onde vc ve "Nexus 4", um globo pequeno, etc, o "Theme combo box" é esse antes do globo, clica nele e escolhe um tema, mas se voce quiser voce pode setar um tema diretamente no teu manifest: `<application ... android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >` no caso aqui AppTheme, mas vc pode criar o seu proprio tema

Comment: No meu manifest esta android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme">, porem o tema que esta é muito esquisito. O melhor tema seria este Dialog

Comment: mas voce tem esse MyTheme em algum lugar ai na sua pasta "res"?
geralmente um arquivo em "app/main/res/values/styles.xml"

Comment: Arnaldo editei a pergunta com mais informaçoes.

Comment: esse aviso vai sumir quando voce escolher o tema no combo box que o studio tá pedindo, pela imagem da tua tela é esse onde aparece "Dialog..." ai na barra

Comment: se o tema ta ok, pode compilar e rodar no emulador ou num device real que ele funciona sem problemas, acho, rss